How to establish secondary database connection after API call?
How can we establish the secondary database connection after API call.currently database is establishing connection at runtime.
Below are the code samples.
Controller code:
  @GetMapping("/updateSecondaryDatabase")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateSecondaryDatabase(@RequestParam Long propertyId) {
                return dashboardService.updateSecondaryDatabaseConnection(propertyId);
    }

implementation code:
public ResponseEntity<String> updateSecondaryDatabaseConnection(Long propertyId) {
      Optional<NetworkConfiguration> configOpt = networkConfigurationRepository
                    .findByPropertyIdAndIsActiveAndIsDelete(propertyId, true, false);
            if (configOpt.isPresent()) {
                NetworkConfiguration config = configOpt.get();
                String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + config.getIpAddress() + config.getDbName()
                        + "?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
                String dbUser = config.getDbUser();
                String dbPassword = config.getDbPassword();
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Database connection updated successfully.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("No configuration found for propertyId: " + propertyId);
                return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("No configuration found for propertyId: " + propertyId);
            }
        }

Here we get all the data in response.
Secondary database connection code:
package com.wairport.app.config;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.wairport.app.secondary.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager"
)
public class SecondDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); // Updated
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/radius?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"); // Ensure this URL is correct
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root123");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.wairport.app.secondary.model") // Ensure this is the correct package for your secondary entities
                .persistenceUnit("second")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

This is the secondary database connection code .this connection should establish after api call and what are the response i get that should pass in the dburl, like dbname ,url,dbusername and dbpassowrd .currently connection is establishing at the runtime.
Can i get the solution for this?
Thank you.

I think that is possible with some limitation you can do something like this:
@RestController
public class DynamicDataSourceController {

    @Autowired
    private DynamicDataSourceService dynamicDataSourceService;

    @PostMapping("/create-connection")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createConnection(@RequestBody DbConnectionRequest request) {
        dynamicDataSourceService.createDataSource(request.getUrl(), request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
        // Use the dataSource as needed
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Connection created successfully");
    }
}

@Service
public class DynamicDataSourceService {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void createDataSource(String url, String username, String password) {
        dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(url)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }
}

